# How can i set type of out data in hibernate select

Tags: hibernate

there was two fields with type [integer] in my mysql db
here is my sql

select a*b as c from table

question is what's the datatype should i set in my model with field [c]

i try to set type with [integer][long][String],that all post error message"argument type mismatch".
thanks very much

part of code :

```
    String hql = " SELECT deviceid,"+ " MAX(CASE cashboxname WHEN 'cash1' THEN cbVal*cbCnt ELSE 0 END) as cashboxonebal,"     
    List<DeviceInfo> devBalanceList = super.listBySql(hql,paraList.toArray(),DeviceInfo.class,false);
    public <N extends Object>List<N> listBySql(String sql,Object[] args,Map<String,Object> alias,Class<?> clz,boolean hasEntity){
    sql = this.initSort(sql);
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = this.getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    this.setAliasParameter(sqlQuery, alias);
    this.setParameter(sqlQuery, args);
    if(hasEntity){
        sqlQuery.addEntity(clz);
    }else{
        sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(clz));
    }
    return sqlQuery.list();
}

java class
@Transient
private BigDecimal cashboxonebal;
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: please refer to that，thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the database, but because the multiplication of two ints can possibly overflow, I assume `long` and `numeric` will also be useful types here.

Since you said "Hibernate", it might as well be `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: thanks for your reply  when i set the type with [BigDecimal], hibernate also post me error message "argument type mismatch".

Answer (score 0):

solved！！！
first，modify sql to [select casta*b as c from table]
and then use bigdecimal in java class
thats worked